# \t is going in one of the primary column of the cassandra table. Select query donot recognize the column 's value in where clause

Tags: java, cassandra

\t is going in one of the primary columns of the Cassandra table through java JSON. SELECT query is not able to recognize the column's value in where clause.

`SELECT * FROM TEST_db.cyclist where environment='test' and cyclistid='cyclist.com.test.abc2\tCyclist Testing'`;

Can you please assist. how to handle this

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the error and your PK definition?

Comment: there is no error but no data is returned

Comment: Can you create a small reproduction example with small amount of data and show the result  of your query and just `SELECT * FROM TEST_db.cyclist`?

Answer (score 0):

Back slash is a special character in sql so if you need to include it in a string literal then you need to use a double back slack \

https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/119

i.e

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_db.cyclist where environment='test' and cyclistid='cyclist.com.test.abc2\\tCyclist Testing'
```